# Will I be able to order meat in Crete restaurants on Good Friday?

Tags: food-and-drink, greece, religion, seasonal

In 2011 I was in Yorkshire during Easter, and on Good Friday the only food I could get in restaurants and pubs was fish and veggies, no meat, because of the fasting prescribed by religion.

Next week I will be visiting Crete, and it will be the week before the Orthodox Easter.

Will I face the same limitation with orderable foods in the restaurants?

Comment: Do you mean you were restricted in what you could order because of your religion? It’s hard to imagine restaurants and pubs in the UK not serving meat-based food at Easter.

Comment: Having lived in Yorkshire for a number of my years, where in hell did you eat out?  I've gone out for a meal in restaurants many times on Good Friday while there and never had a problem ordering meat as normal.  The UK might have an official religion as Church of England, but restaurants can serve what they like...  your experience screams to be to be very far from the norm and doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 6):

This is a really good question.

The truth is that the week before the Orthodox Easter many meat serving restaurants in Greece are closed. I believe you will be able to find a limited amount of restaurants so the problem is not whether you will be able to order meat but how many restaurants will be open during that period.

Good news is that after Easter Saturday people get back to their meat eating habits X2 so you will be able to eat tons of meat.